# what is the value of instance in the below appium code to find the element?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am working on appium-android and want to find element using UiSelector, but don't know what is instance in the below code,

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").instance(0)");

Comment: Basically... instance(0) will take first element that appears from className("android.widget.TextView")...
So if you have X TextView, you will take the first one and stop searching

Answer (score 1):

i will try to explain

**android.widget.TextView** class displays text to the user.

on a given screen , there could be lots of text.

Suppose your application is a messanger application , where you have list of users .

each Text present on messanger screen is identified by unique instance number.

lets say in your messanger you have two persons only

1) Sam
2) Andy

Text "Sam"  will have instance 1

Text "Andy" will have instance 2 and so on

Coming to your question , in order to find what instance 0 signify in your case, you need to open the application and track it via UI Automator or Appium inspector.

Click on text values and see what is the instance number.

Comment: suppose i am on amazon application and searched "Iphone 8"  then among the results how will i track the instance, i tried to click on 'text values' but still not able to find exactly how u r telling, 
Lets say when i searched iphone 8, 3 items is displaying on screen then how will i determine the instance kindly explain in this

Comment: which tool u r using uiautomator or Appium inspector?

Comment: UiAutomator for inspecting the elements